# Ping one computer from multiple source IPs. read Source IPs from text. write results to text or web page

Tags: html, batch-file, ping

I need to ping one IP from multiple source IPs and write the results to a file or HTML page for the results.  i need to get the results from all 4 pings to include TTL and how many of the 4 pings dropped and the ping time.

I know with a IPv6 you can use the -S trigger in the ping command to designate a source IP but how do you do it for a IPv4 environment.

Setup:

Windows 2003 server R2 Standard x64.
.txt file containing 85 IPv4 address i would like to use as the source IPs
1 target IPv4 address
will be run from one central server
will be logged in as admin on the central server

Desired result:
HTML page that displays the results grouped by source IP
Results to include all 4 ping reply times, TTL, total packets sent, total packets received and average ping time in ms

Now let me complicate things a bit.  I am not in an environment that allows me to install any additional software that is not include in the windows 2003 server R2 standard x64 normal install.  It has been ages since writing .bat files and my memory is still very weak on .bat files.  All IP addresses are IPv4.  While I do have FQDNs for all these servers I need to use IPs (for one reason or another)

I have the following to create the page desired and ping from one system to many but the rest is where I am having my problems since I need to ping from many to one, and the only results my script gives me is properly formatted html pages but it only says processing=done
Where have I gone wrong… please help…

Thank you

---edit--- by changing ping to ping.exe and placing %%i in quotes - "%%i" now i get results but not in the nice format i was hoping for.  it gives the results in the format of pining 127.0.0.1 with 32bytes of date: reply from .... as if was just outputing to a text file.  what i would like it to do is show it in a table format.  have made the changes to the code below.

```
@echo off
echo ^<HTML^>^<HEAD^><TITLE^>SERVER PING INFO^</TITLE^>^</HEAD^> >>ping-results.html
echo ^<BODY GBCOLOR=#FFFFFF” TEXT=”#000000” LINK+#0000FF” VLINK=#800080”^> >>ping-results.html
echo ^<p align="center"^>^<table border="1" width="600"^> >>ping-results.html
echo ^<tr^>^<td^>^<B^>ping results^</td^> >> ping-results.html
for /F %%i in (c:\ping-results\serverIP.txt) do (
    echo Processing %%i...
    ping.exe "%%i" > "c:\ping-results\%%i.html" /format:htable.xsl
    echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%i^</td^> >> ping-results.html
    echo ^<td^>^<a href="c:\ping-results\%%i.html"^>Results^</a^>^</td^> >> ping-results.html
    echo ^</tr^> >> ping-results.html
)
    echo ^<p align="center"^>^<b^>^<font size="+1" color="Red"^>^<BR^>Completed at >> ping-results.html time /T >> ping-results.html
echo - on >> ping-results.html
date /T >> ping-results.html
echo ^</font^>^</b^>^<BR^>^</p^> >> ping-results.html
echo.
echo DONE!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldnt it be best to run the ping command prior to building the html file?

like this (obvioulsy change the 127.0.0.1 to your server #)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ping -n 4 127.0.0.1') do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
    set pingrspn!count!=%%a
)
echo Response1: !pingrspn4!
echo Response2: !pingrspn5!
echo Response3: !pingrspn6!
echo Response4: !pingrspn7!
```

now you can use the vars: pingrspn4-pingrspn7 in your "build an html file" script.

nice idea though on the build an html on the fly, i like it.

One question on the /format option on the ping line, i notice that ping does not have a /format parameter, so is the /format option coming from the redirect symbol?

[edit]
so i tweaked your file (you had some missing html code) to format the results (server.html) pages

```
    :: setlocal options
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
        set count=0
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ping -n 4 127.0.0.1') do (
            set /a count=!count!+1
            set pingrspn!count!=%%a
        )
        echo Response1: !pingrspn4!
        echo Response2: !pingrspn5!
        echo Response3: !pingrspn6!
        echo Response4: !pingrspn7!
:: write results file       
echo ^<HTML^>^<HEAD^><TITLE^>SERVER PING INFO^</TITLE^>^</HEAD^> >>ping-results.html 
echo ^<BODY GBCOLOR=#FFFFFF” TEXT=”#000000” LINK+#0000FF” VLINK=#800080”^> >>ping-results.html 
echo ^<p align="center"^>^<table border="1" width="600"^> >>ping-results.html 
echo ^<tr^>^<td^>^<B^>ping results^</td^> >> ping-results.html 
for /F %%i in (serverIP.txt) do (    
echo Processing %%i...     
 :: already ran the ping command, so rem it out
rem ping.exe "%%i" > "%%i.html" /format:htable.xsl   
:: write %%i.html
echo ^<HTML^>^<HEAD^><TITLE^>Individual PING^</TITLE^>^</HEAD^> >%%i.html 
echo ^<BODY GBCOLOR=#FFFFFF” TEXT=”#000000” LINK+#0000FF” VLINK=#800080”^> >>%%i.html 
echo ^<p align="center"^>^<table border="1" width="600"^> >>%%i.html 
echo ^<tr^>^<td^>^<B^>results^</td^> >> %%i.html  
        echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!pingrspn4! ^<^/td^>^<^/tr^> >> %%i.html 
        echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!pingrspn5! ^<^/td^>^<^/tr^>  >> %%i.html
        echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!pingrspn6! ^<^/td^>^<^/tr^>  >> %%i.html
        echo ^<tr^>^<td^>!pingrspn7! ^<^/td^>^<^/tr^>  >> %%i.html
        echo ^<^/body^> ^<^/table^> ^<^/html^> >> %%i.html
 echo ^<tr^>^<td^>%%i^</td^> >> ping-results.html     
 echo ^<td^>^<a href="%%i.html"^>Results^</a^>^</td^> >> ping-results.html     
 echo ^</tr^> >> ping-results.html )     
 echo ^<p align="center"^>^<b^>^<font size="+1" color="Red"^>^<BR^>Completed at >> ping-results.html 
 time /T >> ping-results.html 
 echo - on >> ping-results.html 
 date /T >> ping-results.html 
 echo ^</font^>^</b^>^<BR^>^</p^> >> ping-results.html 
 echo ^<^/body^> ^<^/table^> ^<^/html^> >>  ping-results.html 
 echo DONE!!
 ping-results.html
```

Comment: Doctor DOS, Thank you for your response. the /format was a half brained attempt to format the results into a table the same way I did when I used a similar .bat file to run several WMIC commands against a list of remote servers. I see that the part of your script uses a statically input IP, which is fine for the destination of the ping, but I would prefer to build it into a txt file to pull it from. The serverIP.txt is where I am pulling all my IPs for the ping.
to be continued...

Comment: ...Continued
Now, the real trick is to use that IP list as a source for the ping and then have another list that will be the destination of the ping so I can ping one system from many remote servers from one core location. So for this case imagine Server A = core server where .bat file will be executed Server B= server will be the destination of the pings Server 1-80 = servers that will be the used as the source IP for the ping Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: ok. so i have it working now but just not with the ping command as originally hoping i could. i was able to get an exception to PowerShell and used it to do the heavy lifting and pings and write the results to the HTML.
Thanks to all for the help.